# How to restore postgres data from tar file on windows 10 docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Namastey,

I created backup.tar file for my data volume using following command:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from dockerproject_gobidb_1 -v C:\Users\pp\Desktop\dockerProject:/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

For restoring the volumes, I used following commands :

```
docker run -v dockerproject_postgresGobiData:/var/lib/postgresql/data --name dbstore2 ubuntu /bin/bash
```

and then

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from dbstore2 -v C:\Users\hp\Desktop\dockerProject:/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /var/lib/postgresql/data && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar --strip 1"
```

However, when I ran

```
'docker-compose up --detach'
```

Following is my compose file :

```
version: '3'

services:
  #agar gobidb nhi chaltaa hai to hum db kaa upyog kar sakte hai
  gobidb:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=yavdhesh
    - POSTGRES_USER=yavdhesh
    volumes:
    - postgresGobiData:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
    - 8880:5432

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8800:8080

  #postgres:
  #  image: postgres  # this will use httpd:latest
  #  environment:
  #    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=example
  #  restart: always 
  # postgresGobiData:<space denaa aavashyak hai>{} ye rakhene se hum pehle se sthit volume kaa upyog kar paayenge
volumes:
  postgresGobiData: {}
```

I am getting following error:
[image]

Kindly suggest me. I want to reuse the data from backup.tar
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got my answer, after scratching my head for sometime.
We can automate the process also.

You can manually backup your (postgres) data using following commands-

1. Open the running database container using `exec -it` command.

   ```
   docker container exec -it  <container-name> bash -l
   ```
2. Create a `/backup` directory, then run following command.

   ```
   pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres  yavdhesh -Fc > /backup/db.dump
   ```

   Or you can run the following command also.

   ```
   pg_dumpall -l "yavdhesh" -U "yavdhesh" -W  > db.dump
   ```
3. To backup your data.

   ```
   psql -d yavdhesh -U yavdhesh -f db.dump
   ```

   Or you can run following command :

   ```
   pg_restore -d db_name /backup/dump_name.tar -c -U "yavdhesh"
   ```

These commands are specifically for postgres, but you can take these as reference to create your own commands.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

steps:

Take backup using :

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres  shridhar -Fc > /backup/db.dump
```

And restore using :

```
pg_restore -d db_name /backup/dump_name.tar -c -U "shridhar"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? where will be run above commands inside container?

Comment: We have run these commands in container after running  "docker conatiner exec -it <container-name> sh" command. This way we will be acessing docke with root acess.